# Displaying user-friendly non-fatal-exception errors?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm attempting to implement permission-based security for specific actions into a legacy N-tier application. I need an efficient way to check permissions from within the BI layer and have it allow or deny the action and display something on the UI front.

My current thoughts are to create my own exception class, like similar, then modifying the BI functions that require permission checks, if the user does not have that permission assigned throw my custom exception class. Finally, it should be trivial to handle that exception on the UI front by displaying a message to the user that they do not have correct permissions.

Partial example:

```
Public Class NoPermissionException
     Inherits Exception

Public Sub New()
End Sub 

Public Sub New(message As String)
    MyBase.New(message)
End Sub 

Public Sub New(message As String, inner As Exception)
    MyBase.New(message, inner)
End Sub 
End Class
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: Is there a better, or correct way to do this? Every thing I looked into said "normal execution should not throw exceptions".... Could not find anyone else that has done something similar without using exceptions? Am i missing something?